# How to pass data to PHP via AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm trying to pass data via AJAX to a PHP file, but it's returning NULL.

Here's the AJAX code (with all 'val()' getting a value correctly [I've tested it]):

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: '../utilities/atualizar_ferias.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: {
                                data_inicio: inicio_target.val(),
                                data_fim: fim_target.val()
                            },
                            success: function(resultado){
                            console.log(resultado);
                            }
                        })
```

Here is the PHP code to receive the data:

```
<?php

$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

var_dump($dados);
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting NULL?

Comment: Why did you include the `contentType: false, processData: false,` options, specifically? Is there a particular reason you did so? Try without those, they should not be necessary unless you're doing something like uploading a file - which you don't seem to be.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! You managed to solve my problem. But why setting this data to false led to this issue?

Comment: Read what the `processData` option does in particular, in the jQuery AJAX documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Basically, you stopped jQuery from properly encoding the data into the format PHP expects to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script isn't returning any sort of valid JSON. It's just doing a var_dump of the result of filter_input_array. According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) on that function, the return value is as follows:

> **Return Values**
>
> An array containing the values of the requested variables on success. If the input array designated by type is not populated, the function returns null if the FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE flag is not given, or false otherwise. For other failures, false is returned.
>
> An array value will be false if the filter fails, or null if the variable is not set. Or if the flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns false if the variable is not set and null if the filter fails. If the add_empty parameter is false, no array element will be added for unset variables.

I suggest you inspect in your browser what is being returned as the response to your POST operation to the server. You should see that it is the output of the [PHP var_dump function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) which is not valid JSON, so your JS won't parse it.

You may also need to set options on your AJAX request to specify what sort of result you expect: text, json, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now edited the code to 'echo json_encode(['status'=>$data])' and put it like this in the console output 'console.log(resultado.status)', but it keeps giving NULL

Comment: Your solution, combined with the solution of the
ADilson, they solved the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Marckson if you'd care to tell me what you changed, I'd be happy to add it to my answer so that others might benefit. Glad that it has worked out.